# Decorate a Map to behave like a Set using Guava

Tags: java, guava

Is there a utility class in Google Guava which allows me to decorate a `Map` to make it peform like a `Set`?

`HashSet` is implemented using a `HashMap<K, Object>` where the value is always the same instance of `Object`. I would like to do the same with a `Map` returned from `LoadingCache`:

```
Set<K> mySet = XXX.decorate(CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build().asMap())
```

In order to give me a `Set` whose data expires 10 seconds after I insert it.

Is there such a class in Guava? I have seen `ForwardingSet` but that only works with another `Set` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JDK's [`Collections#newSetFromMap(Map<K, Boolean>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-):

```
Set<K> mySet = Collections.newSetFromMap(
            CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .<K, Boolean>build()
                    .asMap());
```

Comment: Thanks - so the reason it's not in Guava is because it's already in the JDK - that'll teach me to go to Guava first!

Comment: Actually, there _is_ such method in Guava - [`Sets#newSetFromMap(Map)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newSetFromMap-java.util.Map-) but it's deprecated and has been there for old codebases because `Collections` hadn't had before JDK 1.6 (and Guava used to support JDK 1.5+).